# SonarQube Java version used to verify code

Tags: java, sonarqube

How can I know against which version of Java SonarQube validates the code?
Is it the version of the JVM? What then if my project is based on a different version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do confirm that this property sonar.java.source is used only by the PMD tool. The SonarSource's Java analyser uses a superset grammar and so can analyse source files regardless of the Java version they comply to.

Comment: Can you tell me which Java versions are supported then? I'm using SonarQube 4.3.1

Comment: All Java versions are supported, just ask SonarQube to analyse your Java source files. One limitation for Java 8 -> Findbugs is not yet able to analyse Java 8 bytecode and so can't be used on Java 8 projects.

Comment: Findbugs 3.0 is now Java 8 compatible

Answer (score 10):

The default value is 1.5.

To set the appropriate version, you need to set `sonar.java.source` property to tell `PMD` which version of Java your source code complies to.

Possible values: 1.4, 1.5 or 5, 1.6 or 6, 1.7 or 7. Since version 2.2 of the plugin, this property can also be set to 1.8 or 8.

If you're using the **ant task**, just add:

```
 <property name="sonar.java.source" value="${javaversion}"/>
```

If you're using the **SonarRunner**, just add the line below to the file `<install_directory>/conf/sonar-runner.properties`:

```
sonar.java.source=1.5
```

Comment: I'm using SonarRunner or the Eclipse plugin. How do I set this property?

Comment: Thanks @edubriguenti. However your solutions seems to apply only to PMD. What if I use the integrated analyser (Squid)?

Comment: Please could you precise the underlying question/limitation ? I guess you're asking this question because you're getting some false-positives on some rules ?

Comment: Hi @FreddyMallet-SonarSource. I'm investigating the alternatives SCA tools to decide which one to adopt for my team. I've been asked if we can set the Java level and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From SonarCube 8.3 docs

> When using SonarScanner to perform analyses of project, the property
>   sonar.java.source can to be set manually in sonar-project.properties.
>   Accepted formats are:
>
> "1.X" (for instance 1.6 for java 6, 1.7 for java 7, 1.8 for java 8,
>   etc.) "X" (for instance 7 for java 7, 8 for java 8, etc. )

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/java/

In our project, we use jdk 11. We have not set anything explicitly and it reads from pom.xml.

When running on the jenkins, I can see the output

```
[INFO] Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 11
```

Answer (score 0):

From Sonarqube documentation, this is what I found the version of sonarqube that supports java 1.8

[image]

Sonarqube 7.7 is the latest version that supports Java 1.8.

Please tick my answer if this is the information you are looking for..

[image]