# "Exception caught while parsing Xanitizer XML report file" : ParserConfigurationException occurs while running SonarQube Scanner for Ant Task

Tags: ant, xml-parsing, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-plugin

I'm trying to setup SonarQube with Xanitizer on my local machine so that the findings of the last generated Security Findings XML, get picked up by the SonarQube Plugin for Xanitizer so that it can display the results on the SonarQube server.

The analysis of the files and the generation of the report is done manually from within the Xanitizer software. The XML file is generated under the parent unzipped directory of Xanitizer, and not inside the SonarQube or the Sonar Scanner directories.

The Xanitizer plug-in is configured with SonarQube and I can see the Xanitizer rules getting added on the Sonar server. However, while running the Sonar Scanner Ant Task, it is supposed to read and parse the Security-Findings-List.XML file, but an Exception is thrown during the running of the Ant task with the below stacktrace -

```
[sonar:sonar] Sensor NoSonar Sensor [php] (done) | time=0ms
[sonar:sonar] Sensor XanitizerSensor [xanitizer]
[sonar:sonar] Reading Xanitizer findings from 'D:\SonarFiles\Xanitizer-3.1.0\KeurigHybrisSecurity-Findings-List.xml' for project 'Hybris Java Project analyzed with the Sonar Ant Task'
[sonar:sonar] Exception caught while parsing Xanitizer XML report file 'D:\SonarFiles\Xanitizer-3.1.0\KeurigHybrisSecurity-Findings-List.xml'.
[sonar:sonar] javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING: Cannot set the feature to false when security manager is present.
[sonar:sonar]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(Unknown Source)
[sonar:sonar]   at com.rigsit.xanitizer.sqplugin.reportparser.XMLReportParser.parse(XMLReportParser.java:58)
[sonar:sonar]   at com.rigsit.xanitizer.sqplugin.XanitizerSensor.analyse(XanitizerSensor.java:120)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:175)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:262)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:257)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:118)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:117)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
[sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[sonar:sonar]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
[sonar:sonar]   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonarsource.scanner.ant.SonarQubeTask.launchAnalysis(SonarQubeTask.java:99)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonarsource.scanner.ant.SonarQubeTask.execute(SonarQubeTask.java:81)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
[sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
[sonar:sonar]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[sonar:sonar]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:452)
[sonar:sonar]   at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:139)
[sonar:sonar] Sensor XanitizerSensor [xanitizer] (done) | time=2ms
[sonar:sonar] Sensor Coverage Report Import [csharp]
```

As a result the Xanitizer findings do not get reflected on the Sonar Server. I was not able to find any resolution on the internet. How can I resolve this issue?

Versions of softwares used -
sonarqube-6.3.1,
Xanitizer-3.1.0,
sonar-scanner-3.0.1.733-windows

Answer (score 0):

What JDK version are you using? I can not reproduce this exception with Java 8 (all other tool versions are the same).

Nevertheless, it looks like a bug in the plugin, so please file a bug report here https://github.com/RIGS-IT/sonar-xanitizer/issues or send an e-mail with the additional information to support@xanitizer.net
Stackoverflow is not the right platform for this, I think ;)

Regards
Norman (Xanitizer support)

Comment: The java version I get on the machine (`java -version` on the command prompt) is **java version "1.8.0_111"**. I have not set the property `sonar.java.source` in my build.xml but I guess that is not mandatory as per [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289704/sonarqube-java-version-used-to-verify-code] link. I have also not included these properties `<property name="sonar.java.binaries" value="build" />` `<property name="sonar.java.libraries" value="lib/*.jar" />`, but I did not face any issues with the sonar build before adding the xanitizer plug-in. Please confirm if they are required.

Comment: As stated before, it surely is a bug in the plugin. The strange thing is that I can not reproduce it.
Can you please check if the same happens for an older SonarQube version (for example the LTS version).

Comment: The bug has been fixed with Xanitizer plugin version 1.4.0.